# Making sure each async function is finished before next starts in server

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, server, queue

I have a server using express-ws (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws).

```
app.ws("/someroute", (ws, req, res) => {
    ws.on('message', (message) => {
        someResponse(req.user.name, message, req.sessionID)
    });
});
```

'someResponse' is async, making calls to various databases, and the time of completion of 'someResponse' depends heavily on the exact message.  For each sessionID, I would like 'someResponse' to be evaluated in the order that the messages are received.  That is, if there are two messages, the first call to 'someResponse' should complete before the second call to 'someResponse' starts.  'someResponse' does return a promise, so it would be good if es6 Promises are included in the solution.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: it's very hard to understand what you mean, can you use a simpler example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and use a queue. The [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) module has such functionality that allows you to specify concurrency (in your case just 1) and you can just keep pushing to the queue and it will automatically process the queue whenever there are items enqueued.

For example:

```
var queue = async.queue(function(item, callback) {
  someResponse(item.userName, item.message, item.sessionID).then(callback);
}, 1);

app.ws("/someroute", (ws, req, res) => {
  ws.on('message', (message) => {
    queue.push({
      userName: req.user.name,
      message: message,
      sessionID: req.sessionID
    });
    // You can pass a callback after the pushed item/object if you want to
    // know when the particular enqueued item finishes
  });
});
```